# Updating textures in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, unity-game-engine, textures, dds-format

I am working on an external plugin for Unity that updates the in game textures by reading DDS files. So far I was able to get DDS files to load in DX11 and DX9, but I can't seem to get OpenGL to work.

I am using the nvidia graphics sdk 10 for opengl to read the DDS files and GLUT/GLEW to update the texture, but the texture won't update in game. I am trying to read a 2048x2048 DXT1 texture with 12 mipmaps.

Here is my code:

```
// Initialize glut/glew
glutCreateWindow("");
char *args[] = {0};
glutInit(0, args);
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
    char message[64];
    sprintf_s(message, "Error: %s", glewGetErrorString(err));
    DebugLog(message);
}

// Load the DDS file
nv::Image texture;
if (!texture.loadImageFromFile("image.dds"))
    DebugLog("Failed to load DDS texture");

// Update the texture
GLuint gltex = (GLuint)(g_TexturePointer); // g_TexturePointer is a pointer to the texture that is passed from Unity
//glGenTextures(1, &gltex);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gltex);
for (int i = 0; i < texture.getMipLevels(); i++)
{
    glCompressedTexImage2DARB(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i, texture.getInternalFormat(), texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight(), 0, texture.getImageSize(i), texture.getLevel(i));
}
```

I'm not very experienced with opengl so maybe I'm missing something. If you need more info, please let me know.

Comment: You are supplying the data from mipmap LOD 0 to all mipmap levels in your loop. Consider altering the end of your call to `glCompressedTexImage2DARB (...)` to read `texture.getLevel (i)` instead of **0**.

Comment: Woops, thanks for pointing that out but it still does not load in game.

Comment: Also, casting a pointer to `size_t` and then casting that to `GLuint` might solve some compiler warnings/errors but it certainly does not do anything meaningful. You should do something like `*(GLuint *)g_TexturePointer = gltex;` (after calling `glGenTextures (...)`) if you want to make the pointer Unity gave you reflect the texture name you created.

Comment: Okay, I removed size_t. Adding *(GLuint *)g_TexturePointer = gltex; after glGenTextures() crashes unity for some reason.

Also I dunno if this means much but I found out that glTexSubImage2D() only works when I remove the glut/glew code and also remove the glGenTextures() and glEnable() functions. This method is used for sending uncompressed/non-DXT info to the texture to update it.

Comment: By the way, if Unity already gave you a non-zero texture handle then you should not generate a new one. Just bind the handle it gave you: `glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, *(GLuint *)g_TexturePointer);`, and do not call `glGenTextures (...)`

Comment: That still crashes unity. I don't think I need glGenTextures() anyway since Unity creates the texture itself and sets all the properties internally such as size, DXT format, and whether or not the texture stores mipmaps. The description for that function was a bit confusing for me on the opengl docs and I just left it since I was following some example code.

Comment: I would like to point out that DDS was originally made for Direct3D and it may not be compatible with OpenGL, in fact OpenGL texture compression only defines an interface and on top of that you need an actual format your card supports. I think your best bet here is to go ahead and check the format Unity uses, and compare that to what you actually supply. If its not the proper format it can easily cause a buffer over/underflow.

Comment: Why is `glutCreateWindow` called before `glutInit`?  I don't see anything in the GLUT docs for either of these functions that excepts this use from the rule of not using `glut*` functions before `glutInit`.  Also, `glutCreateWindow` creates a new OpenGL context.  Unity can't do anything with a texture object in a context other than its own, and vice versa.  In fact, I don't see why you're using GLUT at all

Comment: I was following this guide for initializing GLEW: http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html
Using `glutInit` before `glutCreateWindow` crashes unity. I'm pretty sure I need to initialize GLUT/GLEW or somehow get the context from unity to use `glCompressedTexImage2DARB()`.

Comment: Update: I think I was able to get the OpenGL context from unity. I put `glewInit()` in the `UnitySetGraphicsDevice()` function which is called when the device in Unity is created. I can initialize GLEW without GLUT and I don't get any crashes. `glCompressedTexImage2DARB` now makes the texture in game black instead of doing nothing. I still haven't figured out how to make it display the actual texture from the DDS file, but at least I'm getting results now.